# DI DbContext in data layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

So I'm trying to seperate concerns of my project and properly isolate layers. Therefore the layers I have are:

`Web`,
`Domain` and `Data`

I've noticed from several answers on S/O that the best designs are especially when the data access is not known and is self contained in the data layer. Since with this approach I need to DI the DbContext in my `Web` project, however this exposes that the `Data` layer is using `EntityFrameworkCore` to the `Web` project like so:

Startup:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
         option.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("Data")));
 }
```

Is there any way to just DI this in the `Data` project thus hiding what the `Data` layer is using from the `Web` project?

Comment: I believe your question has been answered before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-applications-entry). If that q&a doesn't answer your question, please let me know.

Comment: @Steven This doesn't answer my question. The answers don't explore how to DI a DbContext outside of the `Startup` and only DI in the relevant layer, in this case the `Data` layer

Comment: Those answers don't explore that, because you shouldn't do that. Registration and composition of components should be centralized in a single place in the application; a.k.a. the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). As one of the answers explains your `ConfigureServices` method (and `Startup` class) is not part of the UI layer, but part of the Composition Root 'layer'. I urge you to re-read those answers again.

Comment: The solution, therefore, is to register your `DbContext` inside the `ConfigureServices` method (as all Microsoft-provided examples suggest). Yes, this causes a reference from your startup project to the data-access project, but this doesn't mean that your UI *layer* (that currently resided inside the same *assembly*) depend on the data-access layer.

Comment: So in short: Q: DI DbContext in data layer? A: Don't do it. Keep all registrations inside your Composition Root.

Comment: Create a Class Project for the dbContext to separate from the webcode.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to add such Extension Method to the `Data Layer`

```
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static void AddDataLayer(this IServiceCollection services,  IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
             option.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Data")));
    }
}
```

and then call it in the Web Layer as follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataLayer(_configuration);
}
```

So you can hide `EntityFrameworkCore` existence from `Web Layer`. 
The `Web Layer` already knows about the existence of the `Data Layer`. So you won't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you choose wrong approach and you cant DI in data layer. but for your final sentence (DI out side of main layer), we use db context in [unit test project like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-with-the-database#creating-seeding-and-managing-a-test-database):

```
lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_databaseInitialized)
            {
                using (var context = CreateContext())
                {
                    context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                    context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    context.AddRange(
                        new Blog { Name = "Blog1", Url = "http://blog1.com" },
                        new Blog { Name = "Blog2", Url = "http://blog2.com" });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                _databaseInitialized = true;
            }
        }
```

again, this is wrong approach and its completely wrong. DI supply lots of feature that you should use them.
plus i think you can use other lib for injecting services (not db context)